# webpack file loader turns html into giberish

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to copy my index.html to the dist/ folder with the file loader. It does seem to copy it however the delimiters are not removed from the html file. So I end up getting:

module.exports = "\n\n\n \n \n \n \n\n\n
\n
\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

on my html page. Also I noticed that all the \n tags are still inside the html file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to copy this file without any processing, I suggest using [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin).
That will just do the move, example:

`plugins: [new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'src/index.html' }]`